# How do I use a RootViewController when making an app without a ViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to make a simple app from a tutorial that does not have a viewController at all. All the code is in the AppDelegate. I am on xcode 4.2 and I am getting this error:

`Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch`

I'm not sure how to deal with this. There are some blogs out there with fixes but none of them are working for me and I really would like to understand what is going on here. And, how to fix it.

I do have a view that contains some buttons and labels. But I have no "ViewController". The files contained in my project are: AppDelegate.h, AppDelegate.m, and Window.xib only. There is no ViewController.h, ViewController.m

** edit **

I ended up making the app from a 'view based application' instead and just moving all the logic from the app delegate to the view controller. So, I didn't really solve the problem per se. The app works now though. Thanks for the help

Comment: If your app presents any kind of view, then you should have a separate view controller.

Comment: I have a UIWindow and some UILabels etc. But, no actual view controller file. I am following a tutorial from the big nerd ranch guide so I am pretty sure that it is possible.

Comment: Which template are you using for developing this project
View Based or Windows Based ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking at an old tutorial. `UIWindow` got a `rooViewController` property in iOS4. I believe it became required in iOS5 to help keep controller hierarchies and view hierarchies in sync with the addition of custom container controllers (and to fix a corner case where replacing the "root controller" of a UIWindow could stop orientation changes from propagating). There was a WWDC presentation in 2011 that explained this in some detail. I think it was Session 102, *Implementing UIViewController Containment*.

At then end of the day, there's no good reason not to have a root view controller. Apple wants to be able to assume it's there in their APIs going forward. If the tutorial you're looking at doesn't account for that, it's broken.

Comment: I wish I could watch the video, this is the link: http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102 but looks like the site in under maintenance atm. Thanks for the background.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to have an iOS app that doesn't have a view controller. You can always create a trivial view controller, i.e.,

```
[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds].rootViewController =
  [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Comment: I have a window but no view controller. They aren't the same thing are they?

Comment: No, a window contains a view, the window is just a container. An application can have multiple views but only one window.

Comment: FWIW, a UIWindow is a UIView, albeit a special one. A lot of the window stuff is a holder from Cocoa where you can have multiple windows, which you can't in iOS. That said, the coordinate conversion functions on UIWindow come in very handy when you need to figure out where on screen an arbitrary UIView has ended up.

Comment: Technically you can have as many UIWindows as you want.  You usually only have one.  UIAlertView and the on-screen keyboard both create additional UIWindows.

Comment: @robmayoff very useful comment. I always wondered in the back of my mind how those were implemented. Presumably UIPopoverController, too. And (also presumably) it is documented so we can do the same thing too and be okay in the app store ... The iOS docs are weak but I guess can be dug out of the OS X examples to some extent.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree that there may be workarounds, another question to address is: why do you *want* an app without a view? Even if it's designed to run in the background and present no visual interface, at least make a simple view showing the application name and version, a largeish icon and perhaps a status. This kind of idle screen uses very little system resources, especially when the app is backgrounded, but improves the overall experience of the app.

Comment: It does have a view but no view controller. As in the files in my project are: AppDelegate.h, AppDelegate.m, Window.xib

Comment: Just create a new Single View Application from the Xcode template and copy-paste your custom AppDelegate code into it. Then mock up a simple screen like I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your deployment target to 4.3 and run on the iPhone 4.3 simulator, you won't get the warning.

To install the iOS 4.3 simulator, go to Xcode > Preferences > Downloads.